# Pre-Define jquery variable in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have a selection from a radio group pre-selected and have its attribute set as an jquery variable when the page loads. I would like the have this radio pre-selected through the html initially.

HTML:

```
 <div style="background-color:blue;" class="radio" data-value="option1"></div>
      <div style="background-color:green;" class="radio" data-value="option2"></div>
      <div style="background-color:black;" class="radio selected" data-value="option3"  checked="checked" ></div>
       <div style="background-color:orange;" class="radio"  data-value="option4"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.radio').click(function() {
    /*$('.selected').removeClass('selected');*/
    $(this).addClass('selected');

     val = $(this).attr('data-value');
});
```

This jquery acts exactly right, on the click of the div, it sets the global variable "var" to the data-value.

However, when nothing is clicked, the variable is "undefined". I added the class "selected" to the third option, but it only applies the css styles to the selection, it doesn't set the variable val to "option3", as I would like it to.

To sum it up, I would just like to have the radio that has the class "selected" added in the html, for that elements data-value to be set for the "val" variable.

Thanks a bunch!

**Edit1:**

Also, I would like that pre-selected variable to able to be reset back to. For example, if its originally set to option3, the user clicks option 4, great, but then on an on.mouseleaves funtion, for the variable to go back to the preselected "option3". I need this to happen without targeting option3 directly in the jquery, just to have an event that will "reset" the variable to the preselected option.

Comment: What have you tried to make your "Edit1" question work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is register an event handler for [when the document is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), then in the same way you fetched all radio buttons to register an event handler on them you'll want to fetch all radio buttons that have the `selected` attribute (in this case there will always only be one with that attribute on page load) and set the value of its `data-value` attribute to your global variable `val` the same way you've done in your example for when one of the radio buttons is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    val = $('radio.selected').attr('data-value');
});
```

^ assuming that you've already defined `val` in the global scope

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val = $('.selected').attr('data-value')

    // rest of jquery code..
})
```

The reason your code above doesn't define the variable, is it's only fired when you click a `.radio` div.

Edit:

In response to your edit, I would do something like this. Note identifying each radio div by an id:

```
<div style="background-color:blue;" id='radio-option-1' class="radio" data-value="option1"></div>
<div style="background-color:green;" id='radio-option-2' class="radio" data-value="option2"></div>
<div style="background-color:black;" id='radio-option-3' class="radio selected" data-value="option3"  checked="checked" ></div>
<div style="background-color:orange;" id='radio-option-4' class="radio"  data-value="option4"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initial_val = $('.selected').attr('data-value')
    var val = initial_val
    var initial_id = $('.selected').attr('id') //now you know what the initial value was.

    $('.radio').on('click', function() {
        /*$('.selected').removeClass('selected');*/
        $(this).addClass('selected');

         val = $(this).attr('data-value');
    });

    //then some jquery event
    $('.radio').on('mouseleave',function(){
        val = initial_val
    })

    // rest of jquery code..
})
</script>
```